# Is there a way I can force a promise to be filled before I move to a following javascript line?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code:

```
getData: function (
    problemId) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    EntityResource.getEntities({
        action: "GetData",
        id: id
    }, function (resp) {
       deferred.resolve(resp);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
},
```

I am calling this code here:

```
$scope.modal.data = entityService.getData(id);
```

But then in another line shortly after I have:

```
$scope.modal.selected = $scope.getId($scope.modal.data.dataId);
```

As my call to getData returns a promise then I think this is a problem. Is there a way that I could change getData to return data rather than a promise so I can use this data in a follow up line of javascript ? Alternatively is there a way I could make my javascript wait for the promise to be returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**NO**,

this is a goal of `promises` or don't use usync technique like load promise.

Call your second method into `then` callback

```
var myPromise = entityService.getData(id);

myPromise.then(function(result) {
 ...
 $scope.modal.selected = result.data.dataId;
}, function(error) {
        alert(error.message);
    });
```

Comment: Yes but I want to call getData from a number of different places. Can I modify getData to not return a promise.

Comment: @Alan its no matter how many times you want to call it. each call is async task and returns promise. Don't worry about, just send other request